# Bootstrap Margin or Padding on right side of all pages in my site

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, margin, padding

I am using bootstrap and cannot figure out why my page has a scrolling bar at the bottom of the page.  There is a margin or padding on the right side but I do not know why.
http://www.briannaprotesto.com/FreeStyle/index.html

Comment: As a note, try to recreate the issue on Bootply or JSFiddle. Links to live websites are a bit harder to debug and will turn off many users from your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you have a `row` as a direct child of another `row`. Use another `container-fluid` or `col-xs-12` to wrap the inner `row`'s

Comment: I did what i think you told me to do by adding in container-fluid on my index page http://www.briannaprotesto.com/FreeStyle/index.html but it is still not working.  Did i misunderstand you?

Comment: But now you have a `row` in a section, not in a `container-fluid`.. read the docs here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I realize that my code was just very unorganized.

Answer (score 1):

No You have to add a container fluid class around your last row

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      ... Your Free Style content
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome Dev Tools you can easily detect the element.

1. Click F12
2. Click On Lens
3. Hover the mouse on each element

In your case: the embedded YouTube video have (by bootstrap default) 15 px margin right.

(you can see that margin in green color)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLySk.png

Happy Coding

Claudio

Comment: Hi!  Thank you, I do see it but I do not know what to target in my css to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you do any changes on your HTML atm, but it is pretty obvious that you have not open and closed properly containers, rows and columns.

Every row and column must be wrapped inside a container or a container-fluid div.
Everything must be properly closed.
For best practice, try to have each row with a maximum 12 grid columns.
if you want to add extra cols, close your row tag and then open a new row tag and continue.
Unless you do that for layout/style purposes.

If you have not resolve this I will try to make you a bootply mockup later on after work.

Comment: thank you!!  I commented before be accident.   I'm going to try to figure this out, but if I can't it would be awesome if you could do that, I'm very confused at the moment

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I realize that my code was just very unorganized.

Comment: If you need any help with the layout, just ask. Try to be more accurate and provide code examples though.

I've seen that you made changes and now the layout is not teared.
Yet, you still need some mods. Check with web inspector.

Lastly, just for extra knowledge, container divs can not be nested. So you can not put a cont,cont-fluid div inside another. You first close one and the start a new one if needed.

Read bootstrap modification as suggested below.
Ask again here if you have any queries.

Give any positive notes to all that helped you :P

Thank you :)